# Folder bind MsExchange failed

Tags: java, web-services, exchangewebservices

The following code is giving an error from the last line. What is wrong? How can I fix it?

my code:

```
service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
service.setUrl(new URI(getDomain()));
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(emailUsername, emailPassword, getDefaultCredentials());
service.setCredentials(credentials);
System.out.println("Authorize Ms exchange OK");
Folder folder = null;
folder = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
```

separated log:

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.getEwsHttpWebResponse(Unknown Source)
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(Unknown Source)
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(Unknown Source)
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(Unknown Source)
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.bindToFolder(Unknown Source)
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.bindToFolder(Unknown Source)
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Folder.bind(Unknown Source)
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Folder.bind(Unknown Source)
com.prudential.pru.process.MsExchangeProcessor.getEmailRequest(MsExchangeProcessor.java:671)
com.prudential.pru.process.MsExchangeProcess.retrieveEmailIsNotRead(MsExchangeProcess.java:70)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try to write better english next time. Your next question might get closed down.

Comment: okay thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Not being familiar with EWS in a Java environment, all I can offer is a guess.  The exception complains about a certification path, so I'd say your app is unable to get a TLS connection to Exchange because of certificate trust issues.  Can you HTTPS browse to OWA on the same box your program runs on?